Book about an unmanned war machine inventor blackmailed into coding a backdoor into the software
With the advent of AI and the threat of AI-controlled battle, I recall reading a story about an inventor who gathered a team to build unmanned tanks. In the story, the lead programmer slowly goes crazy from the pressure, and the inventor is forced to build in a software back-door. Eventually discovered, he was put on trial and convicted.
I read this back in the 70s or early 80s, I think. Can anyone shed light on the title and author?
Note: it's not related to the Bolo series.
